# firebase: client side validation vs cloud functions validation

Tags: firebase

So I was thinking on using firebase as my backend for some time now and has posted a few questions on various topics. But as my project progresses it got me thinking on data validation and storing more data during account creation.

I'm used to reactjs + nodejs so let's take that as an example:

1. Mongoose: for creating models for my nosql db
2. Hapi: for validating my incoming data

Now is it possible to do something like this in firebase? Although I'll be using client side validation but nothing compares to server side validation.

Topic 2(related to the first question):

Since I'll be taking username, email and password from the user during registration is it possible to use the `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` method and also save data like

```
{
    'uid': 'uid', // will match the auth.uid
    'username': 'some_username',
    'email': 'some_email',
    'display_picture': '', // optional
    'username': '',    // optional
}
```

So, should I do something in the cloud functions and how do I do server side validation, or will the rules take care of those?

N.B: If anyone can provide with a sample code of my `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` that also adds users to collection I'll be grateful

Comment: Answer to the first question below. Please open another post for your second question. It may be related, but it is definitely a separate question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To validate your data in Firebase, you can use Firebase's [server side security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules). These rules are custom to your database, run automatically when the data is accessed, ensure all data access is authorized, and ensure that all data written adheres to your validation patterns.

Comment: so all I need for my server side validation is write good rules?

Comment: and as for the question 2 I only want to know if I want to do it in the client side or server side. Asking for a code was only optional. I mean is it safe to do #2 in client side or a well weitten cloud function is better

Answer (score 0):

Data validation is done best with [Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules), while building your app's model and flow, an observant user can bypass this by making requests directly to your firebase project with the app's credentials. The solution is to implement Security Rules that are based on the conditions you defined, information within the database itself, and the user auth object.

As for the second question, you can create the user with the create user methods, if you do use the email and password method, after creating the user, you must update the profile information in a second [Update User](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#update_a_user) method.

However, this can be skipped by using the preferred [Create User](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#create_a_user) method which allows the user to sign in with the defined email and password.

Comment: so basically the cloud functions+security rules over client side authentication is the way to go?

Comment: Hands down, securing on the client should only be for simplicity's sake, sanitization, and local data management. You should ultimately never trust the client as there may always be an edge case user who wants to introduce their own features.